# Software to help burning large number of files to multiple CD-ROMs

Tags: windows, software-rec, burning, compact-disc

I have 12 GB worth of files (mp3) that I want to burn to CD-Rs. Is there software that's smart enough to automatically spread these files across multiple CD-Rs until all files have been burned? I have tried Nero but it said there's not enough free space.

**NOTE**: Forgot to mention that the platform is **Windows**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed Windows Media Player can do what I was asking for. I'm using version 12, but older versions probably could do the same thing.

Here's how:

Open Windows Media Player.

At the top right, there are "Play" "Burn" and "Sync". Click "Burn"

Right underneath "Burn", there's "start burn" "clear list". To the far right, there's a small box, click that, and you can choose either

- **Audio CD** if you want to make audio CDs
- **Data CD or DVD** if you want to make mp3 CDs

For my case, I chose Data CD.

Answer (score 5):

I have always liked [CDBurnerXP](http://www.cdburnerxp.se/)

Comment: I came here to suggest it, and it's the first post. +1.

Answer (score 2):

**Burn to the Brim** (Open source, GPL) seems to be the program you want. You can then use Imgburn (freeware) to burn the grouped and arranged files.

Burn to the Brim website: http://bttb.sourceforge.net/

Description from brothersoft.com/burn-to-the-brim-64364.html :

Burn to the Brim is an open-source freeware program designed to make selection of files to optimally fill a CD a breeze.

Burn To The Brim is a utility which selects the group of files or directories (documents, mp3 files, whatever you like to burn) which optimally fills a CDR or other medium (or multiple CDRs/media).

Description from burn-to-the-brim.en.softonic.com/ :

Burn To The Brim is a utility for grouping files and folders together in the most efficient way to fill up an entire CD, DVD or other medium. It can output the resulting structure to an ISO 9660 file, ready to be burned with most CD-burning tools.

Burn to the Brim is optimized for quick performance and considers the most promising options first. It also minimizes the search length by fast detection of dead ends.

Burn to the Brim cuts corners whenever possible (without missing anything). Folders can be split up to a set level for more versatile splitting options.

The first priority of the program is to fill the media as well as possible, second is to minimize the number of items (so the larger, harder to fit items have preference and more items to choose from are left for the next burn).

Users can define their own custom disk formats so they can also use the program to fill other media like Zip disks and the like.

Answer (score 2):

[SizeMe](http://lars.werner.no/?page_id=2) can also do this.

Answer (score 0):

Pack in multi volume archives that are ca 700Mb each.

And since you did not mentioned what platform you are on I am asuming Ubuntu/Linux and then tar could help you.

- http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/tar/Multi_002dVolume-Archives.html

If you are on windows, maybe winzip can do the same.

the downside is that your backup needs all the cd to survive, otherwise restore can be a problem...

So maybe it is easier to create a script that fills a dir util it is 700Mb and then transforms that into a iso, and then repeat until you are done.